# Get current date / time in specific timezone?

Tags: templating, datetime, timezone

How can I get the current date / time for specific timezones?

My local time is easy:

```
{{ now|date("H:i") }}
```

So how can I get this for New York? or Singapore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First define an array of all the timezones you want to output the time with, plus what their “Standard Time”/“Daylight Savings time” abbreviations are:

```
{% set locales = [
    { timezone: 'Australia/Sydney',    stAbbr: 'AEST', dstAbbr: 'AEDT' },
    { timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', stAbbr: 'PST',  dstAbbr: 'PDT' },
    { timezone: 'America/New_York',    stAbbr: 'EST',  dstAbbr: 'EDT' },
    { timezone: 'Europe/London',       stAbbr: 'GMT',  dstAbbr: 'BST' },
] %}
```

Then loop through them, outputting your date in those timezones, plus showing the correct “Standard Time”/“Daylight Savings Time” abbreviation:

```
{% for locale in locales %}
    {# Output the date/time in this timezone #}
    {{ date()|date('F j ga', locale.timezone) }}

    {# Is that timezone currently observing Standard Time? #}
    {% if date()|date('I', locale.timezone) == '0' %}
        {{ locale.stAbbr }}
    {% else %}
        {{ locale.dstAbbr }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Gives me the same time for every locale. I'm using {{ now|date("H:i", locale.timezone) }}. So for London the same time as New York.

Comment: @JohannesLamers What happens if you replace `now` with `date()`?

Comment: Its working now with {{ date()|date("H:i", locale.timezone) }}

Comment: @JohannesLamers Cool, just updated the code to use `date()`.

Answer (score 5):

`{{ now|date("H:i", "Europe/Paris") }}`

As per: http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html

Comment: Hi, how to do this same in php, i want to fetch entries based on user timezone.